# Set the maximum buffer size of a web socket server endpoint

Tags: java, websocket, vert.x, quarkus

**How do you set the maximum buffer size for a web socket server endpoint?** I'm having an issue with the server closing because client is sending binary data that exceeds the *Max Frame length*:

```
[io.net.cha.DefaultChannelPipeline] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-6) An exceptionCaught() event was fired, and it reached at the tail of the pipeline. It usually means the last handler in the pipeline did no
t handle the exception.: io.netty.handler.codec.http.websocketx.CorruptedWebSocketFrameException: Max frame length of 65536 has been exceeded.
```

I'm just using the Quarkus Websocket demo: https://quarkus.io/guides/websockets

**[UPDATE]**

I have tried:

```
@OnMessage(maxMessageSize = 1048576) // not working!
public void onMessage(ByteBuffer message, @PathParam("username") String username) {
    broadcast(message, username);
}
```

and

`quarkus.websocket.max-frame-size=1048576`

both not working.

**[ANOTHER UPDATE]**

Just to add, I did some more testing.

In my code I added this to check for the real max frame size set:

```
@ConfigProperty(name = "quarkus.websocket.max-frame-size"")
Integer maxFrameSize;
```

Then simply log it:

```
@OnMessage
public void onMessage(ByteBuffer message, @PathParam("username") String username) {
 System.out.println("Max frame size: " + maxFrameSize);
 broadcast(message, username);
}
```

Here's the output:

```
Max frame size: 1048576
2020-04-16 15:29:23,901 WARN  [io.net.cha.DefaultChannelPipeline] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-1) An exceptionCaught() event was fired, and it reached at the tail of the pipeline. It usually means the last handler in the pipeline did no
t handle the exception.: io.netty.handler.codec.http.websocketx.CorruptedWebSocketFrameException: Max frame length of 65536 has been exceeded.
```

It seems like even the parameter is set the actual handler is still using the default one `65536`

Answer (score 0):

There's a property that you can specify in `application.properties`

```
quarkus.websocket.max-frame-size=65536
```

65536 is the default value, play around with what will work for you

Comment: @xybrek looks like you're using `ByteBuffer` instead of `String` as in guide. This causes an issue for me as well. It's not the best solution to use String, you might need to create an issue on github for this if there won't be any additional answers

Comment: Ah yes, maybe that's the reason, it might not have been part of the Quarkus developer test that missed this issue, maybe they only tested with String payload. I hope there's a work-around since waiting for the next release is quite would be out of schedule in my project case.

Comment: Can you open an issue in the Quarkus issue tracker about this. We do release roughly every months with more frequent bug fixes streams.